# Error starting tunnel Failed to install @expo/ngrok@^2.4.3 globally: npm exited with non-zero code: 243

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Estou tentando executar o expo por meio do *Tunnel* e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

`Error starting tunnel Failed to install @expo/ngrok@^2.4.3 globally: npm exited with non-zero code: 243`

Eu tentei instalar o ngrok de forma global e isso ainda não parece funcionar.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente executar:

`npm install @expo/ngrok@2.4.3`